# RVM + Ruby 1.9.3 on Linux Mint 12 - Is there a way to shorten the shebang line?

Tags: rvm, ruby-1.9.3, linux-mint

With my RVM/Ruby installation, my shebang line is the monstrous:

```
#!/home/kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
```

Is there a simple way to shorten it/use an alias?

Comment: Put a symbolic link someplace with a shorter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing that in the scripts that RVM itself generates or modifies (e.g. executables in gems)? If so, I would just leave it as is; it isn't hurting anything.

Otherwise you can put `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` in your own scripts, to use whichever Ruby happens to be current at any given time; combine that with a .rvmrc that selects the right RVM Ruby.